# My windows has 2 user profiles

Tags: windows, windows-10, administrator

I had a built in admin account created in my windows 10 operating system. I thought it was a normal administrator account and wanted to delete it. For this, I created a new user with "Administrator" account type and then learnt that this account had no option to delete. Then found that it was not a normal admin account but was a built-in. Later I disabled it. Now, my system has two user profiles. (I might not be using right terminology.) That is C:\Users\ has two folders "Man" and "Man.DESKTOP-DT6FVA3". When I install anything, it goes under "Man.DESKTOP-DT6FVA3". I want only "Man" account, that's the only user now in my Windows system. How should I correct my screwed up system?

Comment: Be careful what you wish for: you should always have an administrator account (why did you want to delete the built-in one?) and you should have (and, as much as possible, *use*) a non-administrator account.

Comment: What do you mean by “All downloads, documents, desktop is all repeated.”? Windows doesn’t just clone profiles. The folders themselves are part of every user profile, but their contents differ.

Comment: @Scott: I wanted only one Admin account, So wanted to delete the built-in one.

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, you are right, the downloads content differ, most of it are just the same.

Comment: The built-in account cannot be deleted, it can only be disabled.

Comment: @Ramhound: Yes, I had disabled it. Updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, you now have two profiles, one of which is redundant and unused. Well, the answer is: Delete the unused one!

As for the "Man.DESKTOP-DT6FVA3", you can do nothing about it. I can tell you how to tell Windows to store the profile under "Man" instead of "Man.DESKTOP-DT6FVA3", but how are you supposed to tell all the programs that you have installed to do the same? You can't. At least, it is not easy.

The official way of deleting an unused profile is:

1. Right-click on the Start menu and select System
2. From the left pane, click on "Advanced system settings"
3. In the "User profiles" section, click on "Settings..."
4. You should be able to delete unneeded profile safely from here. (This dialog box does not allow you to delete the profile for the user account with which you have logged in.)

Comment: My %USERPROFILE% points to Man.DESKTOP.. , Can I delete the other one completely?

Comment: Under C://Users, I have some folders like Administrator, Default and Default.migrated. Is it still safe to delete?

Comment: I've added official instructions to the answer.